# Container used to accept remote port connections but added it to a custom network

Tags: docker, networking, containers

My base flask app worked when exposing a post: 8100 in this case.  I added a Database in a new container but I was told that i needed to have them in a custom network together.

`docker network create my-network`

So instead of my running both containers, i added them to *my-network* in the commandline,

```
docker run -d -p 8100:5000 --name flaskapp --network my-network flaskapp:latest
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgresdb --network my-network postgres:latest
```

But i noticed now that while I can still access the 8100 locally with a curl:

```
curl 0.0.0.0:8100
```

Which returns "Hello World"

It isnt accessible by other computers on the host network.

My router has port forwarding to my mac at 8100, so that way it will take incoming requests and pipe them accordingly.  The issue is that nothing else on the network NOR my router seems to be able to access this.

How do i properly expose this to my network?  For a test, I disabled my firewall thinking that was the issue at hand.  Im not sure if there is command I can use in my run command such that it will add it to my host machine proper.

How do i overcome this?  I presume there is something I can do.  When looking at the rules for port exposing, i saw: `-p 192.168.10.1:5555:80` for example, but i didnt want to have to write my mac's in the run command, and presumed there was something I could write which auto assigned it.

**Edit** The way some of the verbage works, is that if you dont set the network or set it to host, it will be available to the host.  BUT because I am adding this secondary network it is adding some complication.  It was hinting that I could just apply this second network AFTER the initial run which would likely work.  The app will fail though if i dont add the connection because it will fail to connect to the postgres db.

Maybe I designed this incorrectly?  Should I be doing something else to link container 1 to container 2 through port 5432?  I was under the impression that I needed to do it by means of a private network like this, but maybe there is a way I could do it in a different fashion?

Comment: The set of `docker network create` and `docker run` commands you have looks correct; `docker run -p` without any particular interface IP address should be sufficient to make the container network-accessible.  What's your host OS?  It sounds like it was working before you tried this; what settings made it work there?

Comment: @DavidMaze Host machine is Macbook Pro.  Pretty much im trying to curl from a different computer as a test case to see if i can get my Helloworld.

Comment: @DavidMaze What I noticed is that on my network now is that accessing in the same network by my local ip will work.   SCORE.  Dunno why it wasnt earlier.  BUT when trying to ping my house IP ( whats my ip ), it will not pick it up.   When looking at my router, I have port forwarding set up for 8100 to my macbook pro on the same port... but it will timeout.
[masterip]:8100 -> mbp:8100